# Command to eliminate blank lines in text file changes special characters

Tags: windows-10, powershell-5.0

The command to eliminates the blank lines correctly, but it is changing the special characters in the text file.

Command:

```
$linblk = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\Logs_LUFS\Lista de Seleção.txt");$linblk = $linblk.Trim();[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\Logs_LUFS\Lista de Seleção.txt", $linblk)
```

Result:
[image]

**Test:**

```
$linblk = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\Logs_LUFS\Lista de Seleção.txt");$linblk = $linblk.Trim();[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\Logs_LUFS\Lista de Seleção.txt", $linblk)

Add-Content "C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\Logs_LUFS\Lista de Seleção.txt" "`n`nTotal de Músicas a serem Normalizadas:$tot" -Encoding utf8
```

After adding a line with the total number of songs in the text file and using the `-Encoding utf8` command, the special characters were correctly recorded in the song names.

Is there an option to use the commands [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText `along with -Encoding utf8` so that I don't need to use the Add-Contente command?

Comment: I'm not able to recreate this but those commands aren't showing the PS command variables and file names at all in my output. If you are talking about it's doing that with the content and your screen shot is that of some player that reads title and other media metadata, then I thought in another post you used a specific encoding with this content, here's example commands to include your coding at UTF-8 but put your encoding in it and see if it'll suffice otherwise with test files.

Comment: Code Example: `$linblk = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($file);
$linblk = $linblk.Trim();
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText($file, $linblk,[Text.Encoding]::UTF8);` but you might need to put something like that in the `ReadAllText()` as an additional parameter too. This might give you some starting points to dig a little more perhaps. Quick thoughts for you and FYI at a minimum. I could test more maybe if I had the file you had if you're talking content of the file and not the file name or what is displayed in the PowerShell output.

Comment: @Vomit IT - Chunky Mess Style The names are from the content of the text file and the image is from the PowerISE debugger. I put a test that I did in the text file and that made the names of the songs correct, see the test in my question. Note: I don't know if I can put the test I did as a solution to my question!

Comment: @Vomit IT - Chunky Mess Style Note: I changed the command to `$linblk = System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($fileSelect, $linblk,[Text.Encoding]::UTF8);$linblk = $linblk.Trim ();[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText($fileSelect, $linblk,[Text.Encoding]::UTF8)`, but it showed the error: `Cannot find overload for "ReadAllText" and argument count: "3 "` I also tried `$linblk = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($fileSelect);$linblk = $linblk.Trim();[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText($fileSelect, $linblk,[Text.Encoding]::UTF8)` didn't show an error message, but the characters will still be wrong

Answer (score 0):

This is how it worked:

The $fileSelect file is generated from the $files. I used the command to clear the blank lines in the $files file, before generating the $fileSelect file. This way the special characters in the $files file remained correct, so the $fileSelect file was generated with the song names correctly.

```
$files = "C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\Logs_LUFS\Lista das Múscias a serem Normalizadas.txt"
$fileSelect = "C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\Logs_LUFS\Lista de Seleção.txt"

$results | Where-Object {($_.LUFS -lt $vLUFpsLess) -or ($_.LUFS -gt $vLUFpsGreat) } | Out-File $files

$linblk = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\Logs_LUFS\Lista das Múscias a serem Normalizadas.txt");$linblk = $linblk.Trim();[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\Logs_LUFS\Lista das Múscias a serem Normalizadas.txt", $linblk)

Set-Content $fileSelect -Value (Get-Content $files)
```